# Flutter : how to use any data type variable observable in getx?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an issue using variable observable in [get package](https://stackoverflow.com) .

The issue is I cant use other variable observable like Uint8List or Map , So how to use Uint8List variable observable in GetxController ?

The code :

```
class ControllerHome extends GetxController {
var name = ''.obs 
Uint8List image = Uint8List.obs; <== error here.
 }
```

Comment: GetX provides reactive versions of `bool`, `num`, `int`, `double`, `String`, `List`, `Map`, and `Set` out of the box. If you'd like, you can create your own reactive version of `UInt8List` using [`RxList`](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/lib/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_iterables/rx_list.dart) as a base, but IMO you should just convert your list to a `List<int>` and use that. Or even better yet, use some other more light-weight dependency of the image (like, say, its filename or URL) to notify your widget for updates that doesn't monitor every individual pixel for changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error that you're getting is that `Uint8List` isn't a supported data type on [getx](https://pub.dev/packages/get/). While `List<int>` can be supported, **Uint8List** is a specialized type of **List<int>** since its integer values are limited from 0 to 255 as mentioned in the [docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.6/dart-typed_data/Uint8List-class.html).

As a workaround you can parse `Uint8List` to create a `List<int>` before using an Observable.

```dart
Uint8List image = Uint8List.fromList([0]);
late List<int> imageListInt = extractUint8List(image).obs;

List<int> extractUint8List(Uint8List source){
  List<int> extractedList = [];
  for(int x in image){
    extractedList.add(x);
  }
  return extractedList;
}
```